# apply lstrip on every element in dataframe of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, strip

In my dataframe each cell is a list with strings. The problem is that each string contains a whitespace infront of it

```
a={'names':[[' Peter',' Alex'],[' Josh',' Hans']]}
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
```

I want to remove the whitespaces.
For a single list i would use

```
y=[]
x = [' ab',' de',' cd']
for i in x:
    d=i.strip()
    y.append(d)
print (y)
['ab', 'de', 'cd']
```

so i tried to construct smth similar for a dataframe

```
 stripped=[]
    df=pd.DataFrame(a)
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        d=df.names.apply(lambda x: x.lstrip()) 
        stripped.append(d)
    print(stripped)
```

which returns

> 'list' object has no attribute 'lstrip'

and if i call

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    d=df.names.str.lstrip()
    stripped.append(d)
print(stripped)
```

it returns Nan lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work

```
df['names'] = df['names'].apply(lambda x: [i.strip() for i in x])
```

**Output**

```
           names
0  [Peter, Alex]
1   [Josh, Hans]
```